# How do I find the abelianization of a group determined by generators and relations?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example
let $G=\langle a,b,c|abcbc=a^2cb^2=a^2cba^{-1}ca=1\rangle$

I know that
$G^{ab} \cong \mathbb{Z}^n
/ \langle (_1) = · · · = (_) = 0\rangle.$
Where $$ maps $w$ to the column \begin{pmatrix} y_1\\\ y_2\\\ \vdots \\\ y_i \\\ \vdots  \\\ y_k \end{pmatrix}with $y_i$ being the sum of the powers for $ x_i$ in $w$. 
So I get this matrix  as an $Im$ of $L:ℤ^k→ ℤ^n$ mapping $ e_i→(w_i)$ \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\\
   2  & 2 & 1 \\\
   2 & 1 & 2 
    \end{pmatrix}
I know that there are bases $_1, . . . , _ ∈ ℤ^k$ and $_1, . . . , _ ∈ ℤ^k$ so that $_ = \lambda__i$ if $i\leq n$ and $0$ otherwise

and i know that $\mathbb{Z}^n
/ Im  =
\prod^n_{i=1}
\mathbb{Z}/\lambda \mathbb{Z}.$
But i'm not quite sure how to use it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It would help if the math was a little bit cleaned up, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some help. (Also : I think the (or at least, a) correct spelling is "abelianization".)

Comment: [This similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982136/presentation-of-the-abelianization-of-g) could also be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know the correct spelling. I have some problems writing negative powers with MathJax so i dont know how to fix some things

Comment: I cleaned it up as much as i can. I hope it's better now.

Comment: But that group is already abelian. Actually, it is the trivial group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : is it ? I found $G = \Bbb Z a \oplus \Bbb Z b/(5b - 2a = 0)$

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Last relation says that $b = c^{-1}$ and the one before that says that $a = c^3$. So the first one becomes $c^{-1}c^{-1}c^3 = 1$ which reduces to $c=1$ (and the group is generated by $c$ by the two previous relations).

Comment: I might be confused but I think the last relation says $a^2 = c^5$. Or am I totally mistaken ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet It may be an error in the question, but it has $=$ all the way through, so all of those expressions are set to $1$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : oh I see ! You're right, sorry for this.

Comment: I triple checked the original task and i didn't mistyped it. I can get another example if its trivial

Comment: Updated the task, I hope this one is fine.